# Implementation of a quicksort function

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c, reinventing-the-wheel, quick-sort

I am an absolute beginner to programming and am learning it using C. I have just learned function pointers and tried to implement a quicksort function using function pointers to determine the nature of sorting.

```
//Program implementing a quick-sort function using Hoare method 
//to partition using a random pivot.
//Function pointer is used to determine the nature of sort (Ascending / Descending).
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Typedef: Function Pointer to be used for determining he nature of sort:
typedef int (*p_compare_function)(long long,long long);

enum BOOLEAN{FALSE,TRUE};

//FUNCTION PROTOTYPES:

//Functions to be used for determining the nature of sort:
int Ascending   (long long x,long long y);
int Descending  (long long x,long long y);

//Generates a random number between a lower and a upper limit.
long long my_random(long long min, long long max);  

//Functions to be used for the actual functioning of the algorithm:
void my_swap(long long* a, long long* b);

long long quicksort_partition(  long long* array, long long begin,
                                long long end, p_compare_function cmp);

void quicksort( long long* array, long long begin, long long end, 
                p_compare_function cmp);



void printarray(long long *pArray, long long nSize);


int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    long long array[] = {5,2,9,7,3,1,6,8,4,0,4,3,5,67,22,3,644,335,345,24,
                         33,25,22,5,2,43223,4};

    long long arraysize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);

    //Testing
    quicksort(array,0,arraysize-1,Ascending);
    printarray(array,arraysize);

    quicksort(array,0,arraysize-1,Descending);
    printarray(array,arraysize);

    return 0;
}

void printarray(long long *pArray, long long nSize) {
    for (long long i=0; i < nSize; i++) {
        printf("%lld ",pArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int Ascending   (long long x,long long y) {
    if (x < y) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int Descending  (long long x,long long y) {
    return ( !(Ascending(x,y)) );
}


long long my_random(long long min, long long max) {
    long double result;
    result = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0));
    result = (result * (max - min));
    result += min;
    result = (long long) result;
    return result;
}

void my_swap(long long* a, long long* b) {
    long long temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

long long quicksort_partition(  long long* array, long long begin, 
                                long long end, p_compare_function cmp) {

    //Randomly selecting the pivot.
    long long random_index  = my_random(begin,end);
    long long pivot;
    my_swap(&array[begin],&array[random_index]);
    pivot = array[begin];

    //Partion matheod used : Hoare partition.
    long long i  = begin - 1;
    long long j  = end   + 1;

    while(TRUE) {
        do {
            j--;
        } while (!(cmp(array[j],pivot)) && array[j] != pivot);


        do {
            i++;
        }while ((cmp(array[i],pivot)) && array[i] != pivot);


        if (i < j) {
            my_swap(&array[i],&array[j]);
        }
        else {
            return j;
        }
    }
}

void quicksort(long long* array, long long begin, long long end, p_compare_function cmp) {

    if (begin < end) {
        long long q = quicksort_partition(array, begin, end, cmp);
        quicksort(array, begin  , q, cmp);
        quicksort(array, (q + 1),  end   , cmp);
    }
}
```

Please point out the bad practises used here and help me to rectify them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things I noticed that might help you improve your code.

### Use `stdbool`

Instead of defining your own values for `TRUE` and `FALSE`, you might consider instead using `#include <stdbool.h>` which defines `true` and `false`.

### Use a consistent naming strategy

Some of your functions are uppercase as with `Ascending`, others have an underscore as with `quicksort_partition` and still others omit the underscore as with `printarray`.  The names, of course, are all legal C and the compiler doesn't care, but other people reading your code will find it easier if you use a consistent naming strategy for both functions and variables.

### `return` is not a function call

Because `return` is not a function call, parentheses are generally not used when returning a value.  Thus instead of this:

```
int Descending  (long long x,long long y) {
    return ( !(Ascending(x,y)) );
}
```

you could write this:

```
int Descending  (long long x,long long y) {
    return !Ascending(x,y);
}
```

Although technically, it would be a bit better to write it instead like this to avoid the negation operation:

```
int Descending  (long long x,long long y) {
    return Ascending(y,x);
}
```

### Simplify your code

The `Ascending` function could instead be written as a single line:

```
int Ascending   (long long x,long long y) {
    return x < y;
}
```

This makes it much simpler to understand the code at a glance.

Similarly, the last two lines of `my_random` are currently these:

```
result = (long long) result;
return result;
```

But the penultimate line is completely useless.  There is an implicit cast in the return and the explicit cast doesn't change the type of `result` which is `long double` so is useless.

### Use `const` where possible

Your `printarray` function just prints the passed array and does not (and should not) modify the array.  For that reason, the function prototype should instead look like this:

```
void printarray(const long long *pArray, long long nSize);
```

### Avoid using `long long` for an array index

An index into an array is an `int` or a `size_t` and not a `long long`, so having the an index that is a `long long` doesn't actually give you a larger range -- it simply forces the compiler to cast (on platforms for which an `int` and `long long` are different sizes).

### Reconsider the interface

The prototype for `quicksort` is currently this:

```
void quicksort( long long* array, long long begin, long long end, 
                p_compare_function cmp);
```

However, it would probably make more sense from a user's point of view to have that instead be this:

```
void quicksort( long long* array, size_t arraysize, p_compare_function cmp);
```

You'll still need your original version internally, but that's not the way a user would likely want to think about using this sort function, which brings me to the last point.

### Define the interface clearly

For a function like this which has the potential to be reused, one would normally define an interface which would be in a header file, say, `quicksort.h` and an implementation file which would be in `quicksort.c`.  The header file would contain only and exactly the public interface functions such as `quicksort` but not internal functions such as `quicksort_partition`.  This gives the user just what is needed but hides the implementation details.

Comment: Two very helpful explanations here. Just wanted to ask a question. Is it recommended to update the question by adding the codes after getting the answers ?

Comment: Good question! Thanks for asking.  Here are [some useful guidelines](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765) about what one should and shouldn't do after getting answers.

Answer (score 4):

### Definitions

```
//FUNCTION PROTOTYPES:
```

Given that you have everything in one file, you could simply change the declaration order and get rid of these.  Function prototypes are necessary only when you are linking multiple files together (or in the odd case of two or more functions that call each other circularly).  They are overkill here.

```
int Ascending   (long long x,long long y);
int Descending  (long long x,long long y);
```

While the compiler won't care, adding spaces between the function name and the parameters list makes this look like something other than a function to me.  I.e. I find this notation confusing.

### `main`

```
long long arraysize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);
```

There is a type explicitly for handling size data.  You may think that you are being more inclusive by using `long long`, but you are actually moving errors from where the problem occurs to where clipping occurs.  In programming, it is generally better to be consistent than right.  Because even if you are more right, you will be wrong in your interactions.

```
size_t array_count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
```

The `size_t` type is what is used in library functions dealing with sizes.  Using it here means that if you add an additional sort that does a `malloc`, that you will be using the right type.

I also changed the name of the variable.  One, because I prefer the name `count` for something that represents the number of elements in a collection.  Two, because words should be separated by something.  In C, the standard is to use underscores.  In other languages, they often use casing to indicate where new words begin (I disagree with that actually, but at least it is common).  It's much easier to read if you use something to say where new words begin.  Otherwise, the reader has to think about it when we want the reader's attention on what the code is doing.

Similarly, I added spaces around the `/`.  This makes it easier to see where one token ends and another begins.

I didn't change it here, but I would prefer a name like `data` or `sample_data` instead of `array`.  I can easily see the type of the variable.  What I want to know is what it represents.  Thus, `sample_data` or `test_data` would best tell me what I wouldn't otherwise know from the declaration.

```
quicksort(array,0,arraysize-1,Ascending);
```

Again, I'd find this easier to read with more spacing.

```
quicksort(array, 0, array_count-1, Ascending);
```

You could also add spaces in `array_count - 1`, but it's not strictly necessary.

### `my_random`

```
    result = (long long) result;
```

This does a double cast.  Since `result` is a `long double`, this casts to `long long` and then back to `long double`.  Presumably that's not what you wanted.  Instead, use a different variable on the left hand side.  Note that you should probably add `min` after the cast rather than before.

Your `max` value is inclusive, meaning that it's a valid result from this function.  However, you add `1.0` to `MAX_RAND` which makes it exclusive of the upper bound.  I.e. `result` will never be `1.0`.  This seems incorrect.

You also just cast from floating point to integer, which drops the fractional part.  This will tend to bias the result down.

```
size_t my_random(size_t min, size_t max) {
    long double intermediate;
    size_t result;

    intermediate = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    intermediate *= max - min;

    result = (size_t) (intermediate + .5);
    result += min;

    return result;
}
```

Now it's clear where we are doing casts.  We have a declarations section, a floating point section, an integer section, and a return section.  We do only one implicit cast (to `max - min` which is cast to `long double` by the multiplication).  All other operations are done with variables that are already of the same type.

I still have one problem with this.  It's quite possible for `max - min` to be larger than `RAND_MAX`.  If that happens, there are some potential pivots that we'll never pick.

Also, this function is not robust if `max < min`.  In that case, the results could be weird.

### `quicksort`

```
    quicksort(array, begin  , q, cmp);
    quicksort(array, (q + 1),  end   , cmp);
```

If you are going to do this, please keep the commas with the token before them:

```
    quicksort(array, begin,   q,   comparison_function);
    quicksort(array, (q + 1), end, comparison_function);
```

Also note that the spacing between `end` and `cmp` was simply wrong.

I also renamed `cmp` to `comparison_function` here.  Given how little it's used, it seemed better to favor readability over convenience here.  This is what Larry Wall calls true laziness -- commenting your code so that it's easier to read later.  In application, you will spend more time reading code than writing it.  It's only in the somewhat artificial environment of learning that you can spend more time writing code than reading it.  So it's better to get in the habit of writing readable code than terse code.

### Comparing

```
return ( !(Ascending(x,y)) );
```

You define `Descending` as not `Ascending`, however this gives the two of them different meaning.  Something is `Ascending` if `x < y` but is `Descending` if `x >= y`.  Better might be

```
// Descending is the reverse of Ascending
return Ascending(y, x);
```

This is a little harder to follow but it now makes it `Descending` if `y < x`.  Another way to put this is that it is now `Ascending` in the opposite direction.

```
    }while ((cmp(array[i],pivot)) && array[i] != pivot);
```

This logic can also be simplified then.  Because all our comparison functions only return `TRUE` for a strict inequality, we don't need an extra inequality check on this one (the other is still needed).

```
    } while ( cmp(array[i], pivot) );
```

Note that `qsort` gets around this by demanding that the comparison functions return zero for equality and positive or negative values for inequalities.

Comment: Awesome review. Thanks a lot. Still reading the parts I did not understand in the first go. Will ask questions if I face problems to understand. :)

Comment: What could be good way to make the my_random() function more robust in your opinion ? Should I add an if-else block and throw an error when max < min ?

Comment: @user211217  A more common approach would be an `if` that triggers an early `return` while logging an error.  Or just swap `max` and `min` if they are backwards.  Note that you don't need those here, as you already check this in `quicksort`.  This is a problem only if you later plan to use the same function for something else.